# Javascript iterate objects in array only after current object

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example:

From

```
[x0,x1,x2,x3] - x0 compares itself to x1,x2 and x3. 
x1 compares itself to x0, x2 and x3. And so on...
```

To

```
[x0,x1,x2,x3] - x0 compares itself to x1,x2 and x3. 
x1 compares itself to x2 and x3 only. 
x2 only compares itself to x3. 
x3 does not need to do any comparison at all.
```

Essentially I'm looking to traverse an array one way only, with every element behind the current element ignored.

```
for (var i = 0; i < boids.length; i++) { 
//boids is an array containing elements "boid"


     var d = distSquared(this.position.x, this.position.y, boids[i].position.x, boids[i].position.y); 
       //get distance between current boid and all other boids in array. 
       //Looking to change this to get distance between current boid and all other boids infront of this element in the array.

     if (boids[i] == this) { //if the boid being compared is to its own self, skip it.
            continue;
        }
}
```

How would I go about implementing such a structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a pointer, I just see 1 for loop. Can you share how comparison is done.

Comment: so even `this` will be there in `boids` array.  So just search index of `this` in array and initialise `i` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; j++){
    console.log(i,j)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to exclude an element or elements from an array

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var curr = arr[i];
  var not = arr.filter(function(_, index) {
    return index != i
  });
  console.log(`curr:${curr}`);
  not.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(`${curr} is not ${el}`)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not looking to remove the currently check element in the list, but rather all elements behind it. Essentially I'm looking to traverse an array one way only.

Answer (score 0):

You might do like this. Shaping up how to compare is up to you.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5],
 result = arr.map((e,i,a) => a.slice(i+1).map(n => e-n));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `Array.prototype.indexOf()` to solved my issue.

```
var j = boids.indexOf(this);
//get index of current element i array.

if (j < boids.length) {
    // if the index is lower than the overall length of the array (e.g. check traverse the array to elements infront of the current element, ignoring those behind)

    //Perform calculations here

   j++; //increment j

}
```